# PHP : simple string to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have strings like `var=test;path=test.html`

I want to convert these kind of strings like the array printed below :

```
Array
{
    var  => test
    path => test.html,
}
```

I tried to use `PHP's explode function` for this task, but this is converting the string to associative array, and then i decided to convert that associate array to the one shown above.

But my own code isn't what i'm looking for, 'cause it contain 2 times `PHP's explode function` and some `foreach loops`, thus my own code will not stand in the department of performance for such a simple task.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you need just one foreach.. I don't think there is an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get an array of keys, and an array of values, then combine them into an associative array using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$str = "var=test;path=test.html";
preg_match_all("/([^;=]+)=([^;=]+)/", $str, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: Do you realize that regular expressions, although they look good and clean, are the most inefficient thing ever in most cases of simple string parsing/splitting?

Answer (score 6):

Use `parse_str` for this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: The problem is, he is using ';' as the variables separator, but `parse_str` expects them to be separated by `&`. There should be a php.ini setting for that, so he should be able to change that with some `ini_get` -> `ini_set` -> restore '&' `ini_set`, but it doesn't look like a very good solution for that..

Comment: at that link i found this function : `
function parseQueryString($str) { 
    $op = array(); 
    $pairs = explode("&", $str); 
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) { 
        list($k, $v) = array_map("urldecode", explode("=", $pair)); 
        $op[$k] = $v; 
    } 
    return $op; 
}`
that's why i call it a great link :)

Comment: => I just fixed the 'explode on ;' issue, and performed a performance comparison on the two functions: see below my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could explode by semicolon, then explode by `=`, and then use [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

---

The solution is really not all that pretty, since it's quite verbose. I typed it out just in case, but you're probably better off with another method.

```
$s = "var=test;path=test.html";

$b = array_map(function($x){return explode("=", $x); }, explode(";", $s));
$c1 = array_map(function($x){return $x[0]; }, $b);
$c2 = array_map(function($x){return $x[1]; }, $b);

$result = array_combine($c1, $c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how you can do that by using the `parse_str` php built-in function.

From the php.ini documentation:

```
; List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.
; PHP's default setting is "&".
; NOTE: Every character in this directive is considered as separator!
; http://php.net/arg-separator.input
; Example:
;arg_separator.input = ";&"
```

So, if you do this:

```
ini_set('arg_separator.input', ';&');
```

The `parse_str` should explode query arguments both on `;` and `&`. This shouldn't affect in any way the filling of `$_GET` and `$_POST` since they are loaded before your code execution. If you want to be sure you don't affect the behavior of any other function calling `parse_str`, you could use a function like this:

```
function my_parse_str($str, &$arr) {
    $orig = ini_get('arg_separator.input');
    ini_set('arg_separator.input', ';');
    parse_str($str, $arr);
    ini_set('arg_separator.input', $orig);
}
```

Two advantages over exploding on `&` and then on `=`:

1. Maximum execution speed since the `parse_str()` function is built-in
2. `parse_str()` also considers recursive splitting: `a=1&a=2` -> `array('a'=>array('1', '2'))`; or 'a[one]=1&a[two]=2' -> `array('a'=>array('one'=>'1', 'two'=>'2'))`.

### Update - performance benchmarking

I just run a test to compare the plain-php splitting vs `parse_str()`, on an array of `10000` query strings each made of `500` arguments. The `my_parse_str()` above took `~0.952` seconds, while the pure-php one (`parseQueryString()`) took `~4.25` seconds.

It would require a larger set of data to test exactly how much it is faster, but it's pretty clear which one wins :) (if you want the test data + scripts, I'll upload them somewhere, since the data file is `125MB`).

Comment: pointless benchmarking and useless function instead of just str_replace.

Comment: thanks redShadow, can you upload your test and benchmarking data somewhere? :)

Comment: 1. I did a benchmarking test since he asked for something that "stands in the department of performance"; 2. What do you mean by "just str_replace"? I see no way to do that with a `str_replace`, plus, the correct way to parse a query string is to use the built-in function `parse_str`.

Comment: @Ranbir I uploaded the benchmark scripts here: http://stuff.hackzine.org/misc/querystring-parsing-benchmark/ You don't need to regenerate input.php (it takes quite a long time to generate all that random strings), just rename the scripts from .php.txt to plain .php and run them on the console. I added a third benchmark script "regexp.php" to test the answer using `preg_match_all()`.. it took 11 seconds

Answer (score 0):

How about `str_replace`?

```
$text = "var=test;path=test.html";
$text = str_replace(';',"\n\t", $text);
$text = str_replace('='," => ", $text);
echo <<<END
Array
{
\t$text
}
END;
```

You'll need to do some extra work to get the proper formatting, though

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the output text in Ranbir Kapoor's question as a string.  I believe he wants the output to be in the form of an associative array.

Comment: ..of course you could then `eval()` that but yes, I guess (and hope) you misinterpreted the output text in the question.. :)